# Динамическое обновление страницы после внесения изменении в HTML-файл

Tags: html

Есть файл типа `HTML`. Допустим редактирую его в текстовом документе, нажимаю `CTRL+S`, а этот файл уже запущен в браузере. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы не нажимать `F5` или кнопку обновления, а чтобы сразу после сохранения в текстовом документе, обновилось все и в браузере

Comment: LiveReload или в gulp BrowserSync

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться https://github.com/tapio/live-server

После установки запустите команду `live-server` в корне проекта.